# Angular: Button text interpolation not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to obtain similar result to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49680194 but in my case it dosen't work valid. The only difference is `boolean` variable. Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Below the code listing:

```
export class SomeComponent {

  enabled: boolean = false;

  toggle() {
    if(this.enabled === true) {
      this.enabled = false;
    } else {
      this.enabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

And html template:

```
<button (click)="toggle()">{{enabled}}</button> <!-- updates only one time (false -> true) -->
<div>{{enabed}}</div> <!-- works correctly -->
```

Comment: Hello!  Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714890/unable-to-change-text-of-a-button-in-angular

Comment: The above code works fine - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2jtex .. What is the error you are facing

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code also why do you even need a function ? `<button (click)="enabled = !enabled">{{enabled}}</button>`

Comment: The text of the button has been updated just one time from `false` to `true`, but the expression from the `div` tag has been updated everytime.

Comment: @Lambalab, did you try my solution below?

Comment: Yes, I did but also not working... @Akai shur say sth about config, which file I should share with you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems to work:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-easley-4ncuy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

So probably your error it's not in the code but in the configuration, maybe you can show your project so we can see things clearly.

Comment: Which files I should share with you?

Comment: I just saw your comment, if it's a new project I doubt the problem it's from config, so yeah looks like it's a version error :S There is not much we can do to help you in this case :/

Answer (score 1):

I tried your case, and you're right, it's weird.

Maybe it treats it literally as `boolean`, not that you want to show value as is.

You can turn around it by converting it into `string`, like:

```
<button (click)="toggle()">{{enabled + ''}}</button>
```

It works to me.

BTW, you can simplify your `toggle` function to be like:

```
toggle() {
    this.enabled = !this.enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with completely new project and seems that is a bug related with version `8.2.14` of angular, someone else can confirm my theory?